# How to use soup.select and what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want my program to get the price of a product on amazon. I am trying to do this with `soup.select` and failing (haven't managed yet with `soup.find` either). 
Right-clicking inspect on the items price gives me this html code:

```
<span id="price_inside_buybox" class="a-size-medium a-color-price">
    ILS&nbsp;53.35
</span>
```

This is my code, what am I doing wrong and how should I be using `soup.select` correctly?

```
import bs4, requests,
amazonlink = "https://www.amazon.com/UNSCENTED-PURITO-Ingredients-sunscreen-Lightweight/dp/B07WQXP3D8/ref=as_li_ss_tl?crid=V29993T4TI1W&dchild=1&keywords=purito+comfy+water+sunblock&qid=1585239706&sprefix=purito+comfy,aps,299&sr=8-2&linkCode=sl1&tag=drdrayzday-20&linkId=7231993512a225ded0b474b852d105bc&language=en_US"

res = requests.get(amazonlink)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser') #creates soup object 
print(soup.select("price_inside_buybox"))
print(soup.find("span",id="price_inside_buybox"))
```

EDIT: my output is an empty list or none

Comment: what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: if you just want the text inside the span,,, `print(soup.find("span", id="price_inside_buybox").text) `

Comment: BS4 has incredible easy to follow documentation.. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @johnashu the output is an empty list

Comment: That link returns `"Sorry! Something went wrong on our end. Please go back and try again or go to Amazon's home page." `

Comment: You can see what is returned by `print(soup)`

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better and cleaner solution, since if amazon changes its html for what ever reason your script won't work anymore, to use the amazon api.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `user_agent` and change your parser to `lxml`.
If you do not have `lxml` parser you need to install it using

> pip install lxml

**Code**:

```
import bs4, requests
amazonlink = "https://www.amazon.com/UNSCENTED-PURITO-Ingredients-sunscreen-Lightweight/dp/B07WQXP3D8/ref=as_li_ss_tl?crid=V29993T4TI1W&dchild=1&keywords=purito+comfy+water+sunblock&qid=1585239706&sprefix=purito+comfy,aps,299&sr=8-2&linkCode=sl1&tag=drdrayzday-20&linkId=7231993512a225ded0b474b852d105bc&language=en_US"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = requests.get(amazonlink,headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
print(soup.select_one("#price_inside_buybox").text.strip())
```

Comment: hey, this still returned an empty list for me?